# Regex for Date and another Regex for Time

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am working on a code that returns the date and time(in 24-hrs). I have a Regex in place that matches when the date is valid. I don't exactly know if it works properly though. Also, I am in need of a Regex for the time. It is supposed to Return the formatted Date and Time.

This is for an app so I would appreciate if the response was in c# please.

Thank you for taking the time.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
 public static void Main()
   {
     string[] formats= {"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt", 
                        "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                        "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", "M/d/yyyy hh tt", 
                        "M/d/yyyy h:mm", "M/d/yyyy h:mm", 
                        "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm",
                        "MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff", 

                        "M-d-yyyy h:mm:ss tt", "M-d-yyyy h:mm tt", 
                        "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", "M-d-yyyy h:mm:ss", 
                        "M-d-yyyy hh:mm tt", "M-d-yyyy hh tt", 
                        "M-d-yyyy h:mm", "M-d-yyyy h:mm", 
                        "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm", "M-dd-yyyy hh:mm",
                        "MM-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff" };

  string[] dateStrings = {"5/1/2009 6:32 PM", "05/01/2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                          "5/1/2009 6:32:00", "05/01/2009 06:32", 
                          "05/01/2009 06:32:00 PM", "05/01/2009 06:32:00",
                          "08/28/2015 16:17:39.125", "08/28/2015 
                           16:17:39.125000",

                          "5-1-2009 6:32 PM", "05-01-2009 6:32:05 PM", 
                          "5-1-2009 6:32:00", "05-01-2009 06:32", 
                          "05-01-2009 06:32:00 PM", "05-01-2009 06:32:00",
                          "08-28-2015 16:17:39.125", "08-28-2015 
                           16:17:39.125000" };
                           DateTime dateValue;

  string pattern = @"(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:1|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);  
  MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
     if (matches.Count > 0)
{
  foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
  {
     try {
        dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, new
                          CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
        Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", dateString, dateValue);
         }
     catch (FormatException) { 
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date.", dateString);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can parse the Datetime directly without regex (code snippet included): https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx or this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9h21f14e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would you like to show date your required format?

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim yes

Comment: I would suggest you to use a chain of TryParse with multiple CultureInfo or of TryParseExact with multiple formats. It would be better and perform similar (Regex has some overhead depending on the use context and backtracking)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("/*Here your format*/");
```

If you wants 24hr format than ignore tt.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression for dates, e.g. in the format *dd/mm/yyyy*, are highly complex and I have not seen any of them that wasn't shown to have exceptions. 
Remember you have to validate the day of the month part based on what the outcome of both the month and year parts will be . . .

There may (?) be a means of doing this in a really complex regex. But it is surely simpler and less error-prone to validate a date in a code function. 
Be careful that the lower limits for the year component of your C# Date(...) function are known before coding the year validation. I have experienced [this curious issue][https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters] for the year component within the range 1-99 for JavaScript Date(...) and had to limit years accordingly.

Time regexs are easier.
A crudely enumerated one for a 24 hour clock with *hh:mm:ss* format might be something like:

**/[0][0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/**